# np.vectorize and np.apply_along_axis passing same argument twice to mapping function

Tags: python, numpy

I want to map a function `f` over an array of strings. I construct a vectorized version of `f` and apply it to my array. But the first element of the array gets passed twice:

```
import numpy as np

def f(string):
    print('called with', string)

a = np.array(['110', '012'])

fv = np.vectorize(f)
np.apply_along_axis(fv, axis=0, arr=a)


called with 110
called with 110
called with 012
```

Why is that? I would not have expected `110` to get passed to `f` two times and I don't see why it would be.

What is my misconception about `np.vectorize` or `np.apply_along_axis`?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/8758

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [145]: def f(string):
     ...:     print('called with', string)
     ...: 
     ...: a = np.array(['110', '012'])
     ...: 
     ...: fv = np.vectorize(f)
     ...: 
In [146]: fv(a)
called with 110
called with 110
called with 012
Out[146]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

The function with just a print returns `None`.  `vectorized` called it once to determine the return dtype - in this case it deduced `object`.

If we specify an `otypes` like `int`, we get an error:

```
In [147]: fv = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[int])
In [148]: fv(a)
called with 110
called with 012
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
...    
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

That `otypes` was not compatible with the returned object

```
In [149]: fv = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[object])
In [150]: fv(a)
called with 110
called with 012
Out[150]: array([None, None], dtype=object)
```

A better, and slightly more meaningful function:

```
In [151]: def f(string):
     ...:     print('called with', string)
     ...:     return len(string)
     ...: 
     ...: 
In [152]: fv = np.vectorize(f, otypes=[int])
In [153]: fv(a)
called with 110
called with 012
Out[153]: array([3, 3])
```

Keep in mind that `vectorize` passes scalar values to your function.  In effect it evaluates each element of the input arrays, returning an array with matching shape:

```
In [154]: fv(np.array([a,a,a]))
called with 110
called with 012
called with 110
called with 012
called with 110
called with 012
Out[154]: 
array([[3, 3],
       [3, 3],
       [3, 3]])
```

Compared to plain iteration, eg. `np.array([f(i) for i in a])`, it is slower, but a little more convenient if the input array can have multiple dimensions, and even better if there are several arrays that need to be broadcast against each other.

For a simple one array like `a`, `np.vectorize` is overkill.

---

`vectorize` has another parameter, `cache` which can avoid this double call, while still allowing for auto dtype detection:

```
In [156]: fv = np.vectorize(f, cache=True)
In [157]: fv(a)
called with 110
called with 012
Out[157]: array([3, 3])
```

Auto dtype detection has sometimes caused bugs.  For example if the trial calculation returns a different dtype:

```
In [160]: def foo(var):
     ...:     if var<0:
     ...:         return -var
     ...:     elif var>0:
     ...:         return var
     ...:     else:
     ...:         return 0  

In [161]: np.vectorize(foo)([0,1.2, -1.2])
Out[161]: array([0, 1, 1])           # int dtype
In [162]: np.vectorize(foo)([0.1,1.2, -1.2])
Out[162]: array([0.1, 1.2, 1.2])     # float dtype
```

---

`apply_along_axis` takes a function that accepts a 1d array.  It iterates over all other dimensions, passing a set of 1d slices to your function.  For a 1d array like your `a` this doesn't do anything useful.  And even if your `a` was nd, it isn't going to help much.  Your `fv` doesn't expect a 1d input.

It too does a trial calculation to determine the return array shape and dtype.  It does automatically cache that result.

Like `vectorize`, `apply_along_axis` is a convenience tool, not a performance tool.

Compare

```
np.apply_along_axis(fv, axis=0, arr=[a,a,a])
np.apply_along_axis(fv, axis=1, arr=[a,a,a])
```

to get an idea of how `apply_along` affects the evaluation order.

Or do something with a whole `row` (or column) with:

```
np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: fv(x).mean(), axis=0, arr=[a,a,a])
```

Answer (score 4):

From the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html):

> The data type of the output of *vectorized* is determined by calling the function with the first element of the input. This can be avoided by specifying the *otypes* argument.

The extra call is made to determine the output dtype.